Which GCP load balancer behind Cloudflare proxy?
I deployed a Google Global External Application Load Balancer (L7) that is forwarding traffic to a mix of Cloud Storage buckets and Kubernetes services.
I want to add Cloudflare DNS proxy & WAF as a layer of protection against DDoS.
One of the benefits of Google’s Global External App LBs is that is on their “Premium tier”, meaning that the client connects to their nearest PoP and then data travels through Google’s network infrastructure instead of the public internet.
Now, is this still a valid point if I place a Cloudflare proxy in front of it? Or would this benefit be replaced by Cloudflare’s network, and I’m better off moving to a regional LB on Google’s “Standard tier”?
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!
